# creating a orogram where the code have to check if the CIN has a @ in the text

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, find

im going to write a small program where the user types in a email adress and the code have to check if the email includes a @: ive just started programing and this is what ive come up with so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Skriv in en Epostadress: \n";
  string adress;
  cin >> adress;
  if (adress == "@"){
    cout << "Giltig!";
  }
  else {
    cout << "Ogiltig!";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use member function find of the class std::string.

```
  if ( adress.find( '@' ) != std::string::npos ){
    cout << "Giltig!";
  }
  else {
    cout << "Ogiltig!";
  }
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string address( "Harald.Scherr@gmail.com" );
    std::string::size_type pos;

    if ( ( pos = address.find( '@' ) ) != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::cout << "The character '@' is found at position " << pos << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The character '@' is not found\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
The character '@' is found at position 13
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your problem is that you are comparing the whole string with "@" which was never the case for you, 
however if you are tring to find the "@" in the input string then you will need to look for it as a char using for loop, you are very lucky however that you can go over the string as an array of characters in c++

try this maybe:

```
for(int i=0; i<adress.size(); i++){
    if (adress[i] == '@'){
        cout << "Giltig!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
cout << "Ogiltig!" << endl;
return 0;
```